# How can I list all of my permissions derived from roles in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, roles

I am not looking for my *roles*, but the derived permissions from those roles.

I can actually get them, but in such a messy way that I am really hoping there is a better way that Azure provides.  This seems a basic need.

## My Ugly Solution

```
❯ az role assignment list --query "[?principalName=='<my-custom-aad-group>'].roleDefinitionName"
[
  "Project Contributor",
  "User Access Administrator",
  "Subnet Deleter",
  "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
]
```

Then iterate through these roles so that I can get the actual permissions from them.  For instance:

```
❯ az role definition list --query "[?roleName=='Storage Blob Data Contributor']"
[
  {
    "assignableScopes": [
      "/"
    ],
    "description": "Allows for read, write and delete access to Azure Storage blob containers and data",
    "id": "/subscriptions/e26acd7c-cb75-4b1c-adf6-07a8eaca6d35/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe",
    "name": "ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/delete",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/write",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey/action"
        ],
        "dataActions": [
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/delete",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/write",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/move/action",
          "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/add/action"
        ],
        "notActions": [],
        "notDataActions": []
      }
    ],
    "roleName": "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
    "roleType": "BuiltInRole",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions"
  }
]
```

Then I can collect all of these roles in some sort of set intersection process, which is harder than it sounds, since I need to consider how `"actions"` and `"not actions"` interact with each other.

## My Desired Solution

I just feel like there should be something like:

```
❯ az aad permissions list --query "[?principalName=='<my-custom-aad-group>'].roleDefinitionName"
```

where I can provide both of these steps at once:

AAD group ==> collection of roles ==> set of "actions" and "not actions" associated with the collection of roles.

Answer (score 1):

RBAC role and Directory role are different.

The command you assume similar to `az aad permissions list` does not exist in Azure CLI. Even if there is, this command should be for Directory Role rather than RBAC Role.

I'm afraid that we have to list the roles first and get the permissions for each role in Azure CLI currently.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "Directory Role"; to my knowledge no such thing exists... unless you are referring to Azure Active Directory.  Even in that case, RBAC (role-based access control) is simply an acronym for a concept: assign rights to _roles_ instead of _users_ or _groups_.  Regardless, you answered my question: for some reason, Azure has not provided a tool for this operation. :(  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Yes. I'm referring to AAD role.